# Let image take space that is left in Column with fixed height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got a `Column` that is wrapped in a `ConstrainedBox` with a `maxHeight`. Now my `Column` has three childs. A text, an image and a textinput. I want to have the image adjust to the space that is left after text and textinput were drawn. How can I achieve that? My Image is loaded in a `FutureBuilder`.

At the moment it just overflows at the bottom because my Image is too big. it looks like this: [image]

My Code:

```
ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100.h)
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "loading...",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp, color: Colors.red),
        ),
        FutureBuilder<String>(
            future: imageRef.getDownloadURL(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                String url = snapshot.data!;
                return Image.network(
                  url
                );
              } else {
                return Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loadingImageFailed,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.sp,
                  ),
                );
              }
            }),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.sp, right: 15.sp),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 100.w,
                child: ThemeInputField(
                  context,
                  _titleController,
                  AppLocalizations.of(context)!.memeTitleInputLabel,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                  size: 16.sp,
                  autofocus: true,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                )))
      ],
    ))
```

Comment: you can add singlechildscroll view above you column

Comment: I don't want to have it scrollable

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it with `Flexible` widget?

Comment: @esentis what exactly should I wrap with Flexible? I tried wrapping my FutureBuilder with it, but that did not work.

Comment: My first thought was wrapping the `FutureBuilder`. How is not working ? What is the output?

Comment: :D Glad it worked out !

Comment: @esentis would you write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @progNewbie You can accept the other answer aswell, does the same thing pretty much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try wrapping Image.network with an expanded widget
also, add as a parameter the Image.network boxFit.fill

Comment: I get the warning `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` when using Expanded or Flexible around it.